# Let $G$ be a group and $g \in G$ have order $2$. Show that $\langle g \rangle \unlhd G \iff g \in Z(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups

This is my proof attempt, if something is wrong, then please correct it.

$\implies$ Let $g^* \in G$. If $\langle g \rangle \unlhd G$, then $g^* \langle g \rangle = \langle g \rangle g^*$. So $\{g^*g, g^*\} = \{gg^*, g^*\}$. From that $g^*g = gg^*$, so $g \in Z(G)$

$\impliedby$ Let $g_* \in G$. If $g \in Z(G)$ then $g_*g = gg_*$. Moreover $g_*g^2 = g_* = g^2g_*$. So $g_*\langle g \rangle = \langle g \rangle g_*$. Therefore $\langle g \rangle \unlhd G$.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Your proof seems correct.

Comment: Your statement is wrong. Take $G=S_3$ (which also is the dihedral group of order 6, symmetries of a triangle). The cyclic subgroup $<(1,2,3)>$ has index 2 and thus is normal, but $(1,2,3)$ is neither in the centre, nor of order 2. The proof fails as you could have that $g^*g=g^xg^*$ for some power $x$.

Comment: I have changed the title. I wanted to assume $g$ is of order 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. Well done!

One thing worth pointing out, though, is that the $\Rightarrow$ and the $\Leftarrow$ symbols are best put between parentheses. But this is just a matter of style.